# Style upon hover

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following menu structure (created by Wordpress, so can't change the IDs/Classes) and I'd like to use JS to change the background of `#header-nav li ul.children li a` when `#header-nav li ul.children li ul.children li a:hover` is active.

Can anybody help me with the syntax?

```
<div id="header-nav">
    <li class="page_item page-item-10"><a>Marketing</a>
        <ul class='children'>
            <li class="page_item page-item-153"><a href="{link}">The Marketing Team</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-148"><a href="{link}">Ideas</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-136"><a href="{link}">Referrals</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-156"><a href="{link}">Partnerships</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

So far I'm thinking that If I can get the class of the parent of the element that is being hovered over (I.e. 'page_item page-item-10' if the user hovers over 'Ideas') then I can set the background using the .hover() function. Not sure how to get that parent class though?

```
/**
 * Highlighs parent elements in a menu when a child is being hovered over
 */
$(function(){

    $('#header-nav li ul.children li ul.children li a').hover(function(e){

        /** Get the parent of the element that is being hovered over */
        var parent = ???;

        /** Set the background of the parent element on 'mouseenter' */
        $('#header-nav li ul.children li.'+parent+' a').css('background-color', '#0066B5');

    }, function(){

        /** Reset the background of all matching elelments of 'mouseleave' */
        $('#header-nav li ul.children li a').css('background-color', '#000');

    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
$(function(){    
    $('#header-nav li ul.children li ul.children li a').hover(function(e){      
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#0066B5');

    }, function(){
        /** Reset the background of all matching elelments of 'mouseleave' */
        $('#header-nav li ul.children li').css('background-color', '#000');

    })
});
```

Comment: Very close - have changed `$(this).parent()` to `$(this).parents('li')`, and mirrored the code in the 'mouseleave' function (but with #000 background colour), and this seems to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would change `.css('background-color', '#000')` to `.css('background-color', '')` but otherwise looks good.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a js function on the "onmouseover" event of that anchor tag.

For eg:

```
<div id="header-nav">
<li class="page_item page-item-10"><a>Marketing</a>
    <ul class='children'>
        <li class="page_item page-item-153"><a id="menu1" onmouseover="change(this)"     href="{link}">The Marketing Team</a></li>
        .
        .
        .
    </ul>
</li>
```

---

Javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function change(obj) 
    {
      document.getElementById(obj).style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Exor, but there are a couple of problems. Firstly, the output of the menu is done by Wordpress, so I cannot change it at all (although I can add a mouse over event in JS if needs be). Also, to my unexperienced eye the JS supplied looks like it will change the background of the element that is being hovered over, not the parent? In the example given, if the use hovers over 'Ideas' then I need the background of 'Marketing' to change. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was wondering though about getting the parent class and then using that the set the background using hover(), but I'm not sure how to get that. Will update original question with that angle of attack and example of code so far...

Comment: David can u put a the above code inside a div. If so u can add a mouseover event there. Else u wold have to follow **anonymously-anonymous** syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant change much in wordpress you can manually get the children and change each one of them

```
var ul = document.getElementById("header-nav").childNodes[1].childNodes[3];
//we are at the ul list...
var nodeCount = 1;
for(var i =1; i <= ul.children.length;i++) {
  ul.childNodes[nodeCount].addEventListener("mouseover",doChanges,false);
  //you could also use ul.childNodes[nodeCount].onclick = handler...
  nodeCount +=2;
}
```

This should happen when the document is ready, if you are using jQuery you could insert this in the $(function() {}); or $(document).ready(function() {});

Now for the handler which we called as "doChanges" earlier, it basically just does "something" to the elements in the loop so just try something like this...

```
function doChanges(e) {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";//or anything else
  this.style.border = "solid 1px red";
}
```

So thats basically for the "mouseover" event which basically means when you put your mouseover the respective li (since we attached a event handler to each), the event handler(or the guy who does the job when the situation happens) does something to each of those li's.

You could also do a "mouseout" listener.

I hope this helps.